# Changing the color for the overlay of a PIL image makes no difference

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library, rgb

I'm trying to apply an overlay on a transparent logo using this function:

```
def overlay(path):

    logo_img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    '''Saving the alpha channel of the logo to the "alpha" variable.'''
    alpha = logo_img[:, :, 3]

    '''Creating the overlay of the logo by first creating an array of zeros in the shape of the logo.
    The color on this will change later to become the overlay that will mask the logo.'''
    mask = np.zeros(logo_img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

    '''Adding the alpha (transparency) of the original logo so that the overlay has the same transparecy
    that the original logo has.'''
    # mask[:, :, 2] = alpha

    '''This code chooses random values for Red, Green and Blue channels of the image so that the final
    overlay always has a different background'''
    # r, g, b = (random.randint(0, 255),
    #            random.randint(0, 255),
    #            random.randint(0, 255))

    r, g, b = (0, 255, 0)

    '''There is a risk of losing the transparency when randomizing the overlay color so here I'm saving the
    alpha value'''
    a = 255

    '''Creating the overlay'''
    mask[:, :] = r, g, b, a
    mask[:, :, 3] = alpha

    '''Alp, short for alpha, is separate from above. This determines the opacity level of the logo. The 
    beta parameter determines the opacity level of the overlay.'''
    alp = 1
    beta = 1 - alp

    '''addWeighted() is what masks the overlay on top of the logo'''
    dst = cv2.addWeighted(logo_img, alp, mask, beta, 0, dtype=cv2.CV_32F).astype(np.uint8)

    '''Converting the output dst to a PIL image with the RGBA channels.'''
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(dst).convert('RGBA')

    return pil_image
```

As you can see, I have these two tuples for setting the RGB. Whether I randomize it or I select a specific color, it makes no difference for the color of the overlay.

```
# r, g, b = (random.randint(0, 255),
    #            random.randint(0, 255),
    #            random.randint(0, 255))

    r, g, b = (0, 255, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

You wish to "change the colour of the logo" with using an alpha matte.  You cannot do this unless you actually manipulate the actual image pixels.  Using an alpha matting approach is not the right answer for this.  I would suggest you actually mask out the regions of the logo you want to change then replacing the colours with what is desired.  Alpha matting is primarily used to *blend* objects together, not change the colour distribution of an object.  I have left the answer below for posterity as the original method for alpha matting provided in the original question at its core was incorrect.

---

The core misunderstanding of this approach comes from how `cv2.addWeighted` is performed.  Citing [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19) (emphasis mine):

> In case of multi-channel arrays, **each channel is processed independently**. The function can be replaced with a matrix expression:
>
> `dst = src1*alpha + src2*beta + gamma;`

`cv2.addWeighted` does not process the alpha channel in the way you are expecting correctly.  Specifically, it will consider the alpha channel to be just another channel of information and does a weighted sum of this channel alone for the final output.  It does not actually achieve alpha matting.  Therefore if you want to do alpha matting you will need to actually compute the operation yourself.

Something like:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

def overlay(path):
    ### Some code from your function - comments removed for brevity
    logo_img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    alpha = logo_img[:, :, 3]

    mask = np.zeros(logo_img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

    # r, g, b = (random.randint(0, 255),
    #            random.randint(0, 255),
    #            random.randint(0, 255))

    r, g, b = (0, 255, 0)
    a = 255
    mask[:, :] = r, g, b, a
    mask[:, :, 3] = alpha

    ### Alpha matte code here
    alp = alpha.astype(np.float32) / 255.0  # To make between [0, 1]
    alp = alp[..., None]  # For broadcasting
    dst_tmp = logo_img[..., :3].astype(np.float32) * alp + mask[..., :3].astype(np.float32) * (1.0 - alp)
    dst = np.zeros_like(logo_img)
    dst[..., :3] = dst_tmp.astype(np.uint8)
    dst[..., 3] = 255

    pil_image = Image.fromarray(dst).convert('RGBA')

    return pil_image
```

The first bit of this new function is from what you originally had.  However, the section that has the alpha matting is seen above marked after the appropriate comment.  The first line of the section will convert the alpha map into the `[0, 1]` range.  This is required so that when you perform the alpha matting operation, which is a weighted sum of two images, you ensure that no output pixels span outside of the range of its native data type.  Also, I introduce a singleton third dimension so that we can broadcast the alpha channel over each RGB channel separately to do the weighting correctly.  After, we will compute the alpha matte as a weighted sum of the logo image and mask.  Take note that I subset and pull out just the RGB channels of each.  You don't need the alpha channel here specifically as I'm using it directly in the weighted sum instead.  Once you finish this up, create a new output image with the first three channels being the resulting alpha matte but the alpha channel is all set to 255 since we've already achieved the blending at this point and you want all of the pixel values to show with no transparency now.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to `[0,1]` range?

Comment: Here are some issues with your code.  One, `logo_img[.., :3]` needs to be `logo_img[..., :3]`.  Otherwise it throws an error.  Second, your solution does not change the color of the logo. What it does is that it adds the `r, g, b` values to the transparent background, thereby getting rid of the transparency of the background but the overlay color stays intact on the logo...

Comment: Thanks for the typo spot. This is what happens when you don't test your code. Now onto your other questions: (1) Because it's a weighted sum so that you ensure that no pixels go outside of the [0,255] range. (2) Ah you want the colour of the logo to change. I do not think this can be accomplished with an alpha matte operation.  In fact this is the **wrong** operation all together.  Alpha matting is primarily for blending two images / objects together. If you want to change the colour, you will need to mask out the regions you want and fill it in with the colour of choice *then* blending after.

Comment: Yea but that's what my code is doing already. It creates a mask that is a cutout of the logo and applies it on top of the logo with reduced opacity..

Comment: Reduced opacity won't work. You need to modify the actual elements inside the logo. Alpha matting is the wrong solution.